# Do Red blood cells(mammals) really have no organelles?

Tags: red-blood-cell

I have read that mammal mature Red blood cells lack most organelles, including mitochondria, golgi apparatus and an ER. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_blood_cell#Mammalian_erythrocytes ) This makes sense since there purpose is to transport oxygen via hemoglobin, and according to the wiki, they make any energy needed via glycolysis. But are there really no more organelles in a mature red blood cells? A simple google search did not help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. This is true. During the final stages of red blood cell formation in the bone marrow, the nucleus and several other organelles are broken down and/or expelled from the cells. In the process they decrease markedly in size, from about 24 to about 7-9 micrometer. Presumably this makes them small enough to pass through the smallest capillaries. Lacking those organelles also limits their life expectancy to approximately 120 days.